# jQuery- I need to hide contents of div according to option, then restore the original contents... how?

Tags: jquery, dom, replace, reset

**edit: Added my exact code, rather than a simplified example**

StackOverflow. I have a list of options, and when they are clicked, they populate the page with a variable from an array. The close button should replace this new content with the original.

It works up to that point, but due to the nature of the DOM, things get forgotten. I've researched and experimented, but again I fall back to your guidance.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twwuuqj9/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="main_container">
<a name="top"></a>
<b class="tstmnl_close">[close]</b>
<div class="main_right" id="tstmnl_right">
    
    <div class="tstmnl_column">
        <div class="testimonials">
            Testimonial 1
            <a href="#top" class="tstmnl_readmore" data-value="1">[read more]</a>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="testimonials">
            Testimonial 2
            <a href="#top" class="tstmnl_readmore" data-value="2">[read more]</a>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="testimonials">
            Testimonial 3
            <a href="#top" class="tstmnl_readmore" data-value="3">[read more]</a>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
    var content = [
            "<b>Testimonial 1</b>",
            "Testimonial 2",
            "Testimonial 3"
            ];

$(document).ready(function () {
    
var original = $('#tstmnl_right').clone();

    $('.main_container').on('click', '.tstmnl_readmore', function() {
        var dataValue = $(this).data("value");
        $('#tstmnl_right').empty().append(content[dataValue]-1);
    });

    $('.tstmnl_close').click(function() {
        $('#tstmnl_right').replaceWith(original.clone());
    });
});
```

I have seen the examples on here, but none seem to fit this application. Many others on other boards have found solutions to this same problem, but for some reason they are not solutions to this! I've seen this done several times, there has to be something I'm overlooking.

Thank you for looking.

Comment: Don't empty the original content, hide it and then show it on close

Comment: may be this will help you. i have apply small changes in code 

https://jsfiddle.net/ocjnxww1/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to store the `data-value` in a variable as when you call `.empty()` on parent element there is data loss.
2. Since you are creating elements dynamically, You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

*Use*

```
$('.main').on('click', '.options', function() {
    var dataValue = $(this).data("value");
    $('.stuff').empty().append(content[dataValue]);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/jony66fw/)

Comment: Thank you very much for this... but for some reason this won't work with my code. It works in the jsFiddle... there should be no reason it doesn't work on my page! This is frustrating. Here is a better example of what I'm working with (should have posted in the first place) https://jsfiddle.net/twwuuqj9/1/ ... see anything I'm missing? Thanks again for this example, I tried using a listener earlier but failed.

Comment: @user2959040 https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/zydu0pvk/1/   changes `content[dataValue - 1]`